# Drupal: views display as a block; putting inside an html tab

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

Drupal 6.28:

I'm re-theming a particular section of a site and the new design called for five pages to be displayed as five tabs on one page with the appropriate one shown when either clicking on the tab itself or in an expanded menu to the left.

I created all that in html and jquery so that I could deep-link the tabs, ie... someone can click on any menu link and hit the page with the appropriate tab open instead of having to go to the master page and then click the appropriate tab. (using location.hash)

This is all working fine, but the last tab is to house content that currently is a view set as a block.

What is the best way to pull that view/block into the html div I have set aside for that specific content?

I have used this great snippet before:

```
<?php
 $block = module_invoke('block', 'block', 'view', '15');
       print $block['content']; 
?>
```

which allows one to place any block anywhere, but with a view with a display set as a block, I'm not having any luck invoking that view. Also, I'd had to have to use "php" instead of 'full html' on the node since it's just a snippet but as it's not currently working, it probably doesn't matter.

so, I'm trying to figure out how to have something like this:

```
<!-- all the other tabs content-->
<div id="fifthTab">
all the content from the view which is set to 'display like a block'
</div>
```

I'm fairly new to Drupal and not even sure if I create a page display how I would call that data anyway.

So my html structure is:
MAIN PAGE LINK
-sub link/tab 1/default
-sub link/tab 2
-sub link/tab3
-sub link/tab4
-sub link/tab5

So if someone either clicks on on the sub link/tab 5 in the left nav or clicks on the actual tab 5 or enters the url xxx/#tab5, the appropriate tab is show, the rest hidden. That's all working great, I just cant get the view content to show in that tab5.

Comment: also, the cheat would be to view the page, view source and cut-n-paste the html but if new docs were added in the future, they would have to be added in the db and the html. Just to mention that I've thought of that.

Answer (score 0):

so a page template based on the url is the easiest. The variable $content is just placed in the last tab and all other html content for that specific page is just put in the template.

At least this way, as docs are added, it's still dynamic and the static info is easy to edit if needed.

Just in case something similar comes up for someone else.